# How does the old version of Trackmania differ from TrackMania Nations Forever?

Tags: version-differences, trackmania-forever

I played [TrackMania](http://www.trackmania.com/) long before it was available on Steam. I'm unsure but I recall it having a different map editor and different tiles than the current free version, TrackMania Nations Forever. How do the two versions differ, specifically in gameplay and maps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Trackmania has a pretty unusual release/upgrade path, where three games have become 1 game with a demo.

- It all started with **Trackmania**
- Then came the second game **Trackmania Sunrise** which ran on an improved engine
- *Trackmania Sunrise* got an free upgrade to **Trackmania Sunrise eXtreme**
- Then *Trackmania* got an free upgrade to **Trackmania Original** which ran on the same engine as *Trackmania Sunrise*
- As a promotion for the Trackmania games and the Electronic Sports World Cup **TrackMania Nations** gets released for free.

Now we have three different trackmania games, and here is where it gets unusual.

- a Fourth Trackmania game, **Trackmania United** gets released containing basically all content from the previous games.
- *TrackMania Nations* gets updated to the same codebase as *Trackmania United*, and forever get's added to the name, resulting in **TrackMania Nations Forever** and **Trackmania United Forever**

As the codebase, including the shared stages and the networking code between the games is now the same, *TrackMania Nations Forever* is now nothing more than a demo for *TrackMania United Forever* and *TrackMania United Forever* includes everything that is in *TrackMania Nations Forever*.

(afterwards, there was a contest and corresponding free update, which updated it to **TrackMania United Forever: Star Edition** )

So effectively, the trackmania now availble on steam, is an updated re-release of the previous trackmania games all together.
The free edition is what used to be a seperate game, updated to be a demo of the full game.

*TrackMania Nations Forever* consists of a single stage (Stadium), first seen in *TrackMania Nations* while *TrackMania United Forever: Star Edition* consists of all stages of all the previous Trackmania games.

- Stadium (*TrackMania Nations*)
- Desert (*TrackMania*)
- Rally (*TrackMania*)
- Snow (known in *TrackMania* as Alpine)
- Bay (*TrackMania Sunrise*)
- Coast (*TrackMania Sunrise*)
- Island (*TrackMania Sunrise*)

More information can be found in the [Trackmania Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrackMania)

Comment: I started to get lost around mid answer (wow that's a lot of games, I only knew of three of those!) but now I know the Steam one missed nothing from the old one, thanks :)

Comment: This Answer definitly deserves way more interest.

Comment: And there are now three versions of TrackMania2: Canyon, Stadium, and Valley.